# How can I check if recv is empty from my client socket

Tags: python

I have a client sending messages every second.

I'm trying to implement a KeepALIVE method: If no message have been sent in the last 5 seconds then the client should send a KeepALIVE message to let the server know we still want it to stay alive.

The way I want to handle it is: If KeepALIVE is set to true in my ini fil then make client send an empty message. Then I want the server to check if the recv from the client is empty, if it is empty then it should a message back to the client to send a keepAlive message.

I tried to check data like this:

```
data = s.recv(1024)
if data == "";
 #do something
```

I tried with coding my client to send an empty message to test it, but it does not work.

```
     msg = ""
            s.send(msg.encode())
```

Is it wrong to use "" as an empty message in python when it comes to sockets?
If I set my client to send a empty message such as ="" it wont return true in my if data =="";

Comment: Sockets read bytes. An empty string is the absence of bytes, and so is indistinguishable from no message at all. You have to send *something*.

Comment: Whatever protocol you are using or designing needs to have a non-empty string of bytes that represents an otherwise "empty" message.

Comment: Yeah, there's no such thing as an 'empty message' in this case, because a truly empty message would be zero bytes long.  Instead you need some kind of simple wire protocol that allows your client and server to distinguish keep-alive messages from other messages.

Comment: Put another way, `""` is what `recv` returns when a non-blocking read has nothing to read. A blocking read would always return a non-empty string.

Comment: Do I understand both of you correct if it means I just can set it to whatever, lets say "emptymsg" to represent an empty message? 

@chepner I'm trying to setup my own protocol.

Comment: Correct. However, there's no guarantee that "emptymsg" will be received as a single read. Wire protocols tend to be based on binary data, where receiving even a single byte is sufficient to determine if there is more to come for a single message.

Comment: For example, one simple scheme is to start every message with a fixed-size byte count indicating the length of the rest of the message.  Let's say you decide no message is more than 65K bytes. Then every message starts with a 2-byte integer. If you read only one byte, you know you have to wait for the second byte to arrive. Once you have at least 2 bytes, you can decode that to know how many more bytes to expect in order to receive a single complete message.

Comment: Using that, a keepalive would simply be a pair of null bytes, `\x00\x00`, indicating no further data after the length is received.

Comment: I understand @chepner this is exactly the problem I just ran into now that I set my message to something as "emptymsg".  I need to use a fixed-size byte that make sense. I will look into it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, if you really want to avoid imposing a protocol on your in-bound data, is you can also send commands using an [out-of-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_data) channel.

You can do this with TCP sockets as follows (note: you can only place one byte of OOB data on the stream at a time; if you send one bytes OOB and then send another it will replace the first one).  But you can do this to send a simple 1-byte command over the stream without directly interleaving it with your in-bound messages.  Here's an example:

// server

```
>>> import socket                                                               
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                       
>>> s.bind(('', 5555))                                                          
>>> s.listen()                                                                  
>>> conn, addr = s.accept()
```

// client

```
>>> import socket                                                               
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                       
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 5555))                                              
>>> s.send(b'abcdefg')
```

// server: now on the server I can read some data sent from the client

```
>>> conn.recv(2)                                                                
b'ab'
```

// client: now the client sends an OOB command

```
>>> s.send(b'a', socket.MSG_OOB)                                                
1
```

// server: the server (in its event loop, or whatever) checks if there's OOB data

```
>>> conn.recv(1, socket.MSG_OOB)
b'a'
```

(note: if there is no OOB data here, `recv` will raise an `EINVAL`)

// server: the server can continue reading the in-bound data at any time

```
>>> conn.recv(5)
b'cdefg'
```